# CMOS Battery Replacement Ml 1220 to CR 1220

Tags: battery, replacement

[image]

I have a Gigabyte Q1000C mini Laptop. The Bios battery is dead, as it has been in storage for the last 3 Years.

The bios battery in it now is a ML 1220 - as shown above. I'd like to know if I could replace it with a CR 1220? The current one is rechargeable. I believe the CR versions are non rechargeable.

Do not want to try it and damage the Laptop. The ML 1220 versions are just not available around my area I stay.

Comment: Ouch thought as much, as there is a reason the battery is rechargeable. Im stuffed cause no one really stocks this battery anymore. Thanks for the reply Chenmunka.

Comment: They are easily available online. E.g Amazon and the likes have them.

Answer (score 1):

Damage the laptop - indirectly.  Damage the battery - probably.

Your motherboard will still try to charge the CR1220.  Putting such voltage across a non-rechargeable lithium cell is not a good idea.

Apart from overheating, it could damage the battery.  Worst case, it will catch fire.

Comment: Or explode. That is also a possibliity...

Comment: I'd put the worst case right at the top, there's no "possibly" here. The battery **will** over-heat, which will cause it to expand [non-rechargeables are firmly sealed] will **probably** burst & leak, spilling toxic & corrosive chemicals inside the computer & **may** catch fire.

Answer (score 0):

According to a quick search using the battery identifier, Amazon and Walmart (online) both have this particular battery available. Walmart indicates one remaining, while one of the [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=ML%201220&ref=nb_sb_noss_2) sources show ten. Both locations reference rechargeable capability, ensuring the safety of your computer. One type shown requires soldering, while another appears to be the slip-in type.

[image: computer battery]

Image via amazon search page.

Comment: Unfortunately i am in South Africa. The battery is non Soldered both sides clean.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Adamo-Reserve-Battery-U882J/dp/B00K0JVSUM/ref=sr_1_10?crid=2MZUOJN0ZBHGE&dchild=1&keywords=ml+1220+battery&qid=1631025431&sprefix=ml+1220%2Caps%2C393&sr=8-10

Comment: @Rudeman https://za.rs-online.com/web/p/button-rechargeable-batteries/1839496/

Comment: This could possibly work. Will check with them and let you know. Thanks